# android testing with touchUtils: grabbing button within RelativeLayout that has no id

Tags: android, testing, button

I'm trying to do some `touchUtil` on a button within a relative layout that does not have an id.
Usually it would look something like:

```
relativelayout rl1 = (relativelayout) base.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
button btn = (button) rl1.findviewbyId(R.id.buttonX);
touchUtil(btn);
```

But the one I'm working on is within a ScrollView, RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, (which do not have ids) and then the button.

How can I push that button with touchutils?

Comment: im not sure if i should just add ids for them because other people are working on those xmls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use [`ViewGroup#getChildAt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) to retrieve a View based on an index.

---

**Addition**
If you have a layout like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then you can traverse the ViewTree like so:

```
FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) content.getChildAt(0);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) scrollView.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) relativeLayout.getChildAt(0);

Button button1 = (Button) linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
Button button2 = (Button) linearLayout.getChildAt(1);

TextView textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);
```

**The best** scenario is to simply ask the layout designers to add ids to the elements that you want.

Comment: i think that is one of the problems, there is no base(with an id) for me to work from

Comment: Every View is a descendent of `android.R.id.content`, at the very least you can climb down the ViewTree from here: `findViewById(android.R.id.content);`

Comment: can you tell me more about android.r.id.content? how do i find out how to navigate to the view i want? is there a visual rep of the tree?

Comment: I added an example to my answer. "is there a visual rep of the tree?" You can use the [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) tool during development to see the layout in realtime.